# Does creating Selenium test cases for C# require Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am aware that you can use Java using Eclipse an Python etc... but my question is more towards writing a test script in C# and testing....

How can the QA team test cases if i have those written in C#? do they need to have a Visual Studio?

The other question I have is is there any other way (other than Selenium IDE) we can test the test cases (written in C#) without using the Visual Studio?

Comment: The [home page](http://seleniumhq.org/) says you can run Selenium tests in a Firefox plugin.

Comment: Robert: I am aware of the IDE plugin in FF

Comment: I think you can make use of <a href="http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/">Sharp Develop </a>which is a free IDE for C# <br>

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a framework that sits on top of selenium. For example, the [robot framework](http://Robotframework.org) lets you testers write tests with any editor. You create keywords, then write tests using these keywords.